# How to Climb a cube on wall in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to climb a cube over walls, I have written a code to roll a cube but I also need to climb over wall when hit it.

I have tried Box-Collider and rigid body and change the position of cube player and set to the position of wall.

```
// roll a cube player 

  IEnumerator moveLeft()
{
      for (int i = 0; i < (90 / step); i++)
      {
          Player.transform.RotateAround(Left.transform.position, 
         Vector3.forward, step);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(speed);
      }

      Center.transform.position = Player.transform.position;
      input = true;
}


 // try to Climb a wall

 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("hill"))
    {
        //collider = collision.gameObject;
        //isGrounded = false;
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().drag = 20;
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;

    }
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("floor"))
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().drag = 1;
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        isGrounded = true;
    }


}
```

It climbs but it doesn't snap with wall. I need to climb walls in snap mode and if there isn't any wall the player should be dropped.

I need to have the following kind of feature shown in video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fo-7kKeb-TM

[Image of my player movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlwvY.png)

I have also tried the following code but not succeeded.

```
void moveLeft()
{
    rotationModifier = 90f;
    appliedVector = Vector3.left;
    appliedRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90f, Vector3.forward);

    previousPosition = rb.position;
    previousRotation = rb.rotation;

    targetPosition = previousPosition + appliedVector;
    targetRotation = previousRotation * appliedRotation;
    Player.transform.position = targetPosition;
    Player.transform.rotation = targetRotation;

}
```

Comment: If something like that video is what you want as your end goal, then you may want to rethink your approach. Rather than thinking in terms of the other cube's position, think in terms of the corner's of the boxes. You want to line up the corners. When you rotate clockwise, you're rotating around your bottom-right corner until your top-right corner is touching another boxes corner. When counter-clockwise, it's around your bottom-left corner until your top-left corner is touching another boxes corner. From there, just figure out how to identify and orientate the corners appropriately.

Comment: As for how to identify the corners, you can use raycasts out of each side of the cube to check for an "open-space" vs a "occupied-space". If you have 3 open spaces, then the 2 corners you want to track for rotation contact are between those three open surfaces. If 2 open spaces, the the 1 corner of contact is between the two open spaced surfaces. And if 1 open space, then the corners to rotate around are the corners of that one open spaced surface.

Comment: I have create empty objects as center, left , right, up and down to rotate my cube which works perfectly.. but now I need to snap and climb the wall